# How to add text style to some characters in between a Text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-sketchapp

I am looking for a work around to [this React-SketchApp bug](https://github.com/airbnb/react-sketchapp/issues/44).

At time of posting this, my solution was to use flexbox on text that's not nested and give it the appearance that it's nested.

```
<Text style={myStyle}>This is a </Text><Bold>word</Bold><Text> in a sentence.</Text>
```

With a Style of:

```
flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-start;
```

This will work for a situation where text is on the same line. But how about if say a bolded element is within a text block and not on a simple line, what can I do then? Maybe some fancy CSS or javascript trick?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by nested `Text` component as described in react native documentations [nested text](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#nested-text)

```
<Text style={myStyle}>This is a 
  <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}> word</Text> in a sentence.
</Text>
```

Comment: Kindly make a practice of adding a descriptive description of your code, as how this work and/or the reason behind doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `<Text>` tag as `<p>`, `<span>` tag similar in HTML. You can use both `<Text>` as a block and inline level element. 
What you are trying to achieve you can do by,

```
<Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>I am a an amazing 
  <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}> green</Text> line. I hope you 
  like it. or you can even do multiple nesting 
  <Text style={{ fontSize: '16'}}> of 
    <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}> multiple</Text> 
    elements
  </Text>
</Text>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, nested TEXT tags don't work right now with React-SketchApp as its a known bug (see link above). However react-SketchApp have such promise that I wanted a workaround till the bug gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You went in the right direction with `flexDirection: 'row'` for a workaround but you still need to nest `Text` elements like so:

```
<Text style={{flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  This is a <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>bold word</Text> in a sentence
</Text>
```